Issues Installing "BiblioteQ" (GitHub Program for library and archival management) using Qt compiler on Windows?
I'm relatively inexperienced with C++ and compilers, but I'm doing my best to learn so I can install an archival/library management program for home use.
The program is called BiblioteQ and is hosted on GitHub as an open source/open access program with Windows installation available using Qt (compiler). Instructions for Windows installation are as follows (provided by Dev):
(1) Qt Preparation (completed)
(2) Building BiblioteQ
(3) Preparing BiblioteQ Release
Where I'm stuck is understanding the instructions of part 2. The instructions for "Building BiblioteQ" are as follows:

Place the source directory of the BiblioteQ application onto the Windows desktop.
Open a Qt DOS terminal.
In the DOS terminal, proceed to the main BiblioteQ directory.
Issue a qmake -o Makefile biblioteq.win.pro.
At the prompt, issue mingw32-make.
Wait until the application is generated.
Issue a mingw32-make install.
Wait until the various files are copied into the release folder.
Issue a mingw32-make clean

I've placed the source directory on the desktop, but I'm struggling with understanding how/what to do on the following steps.
So far, I have installed Qt, downloaded the program .zip file from GitHub, and extracted the source directory to desktop per the dev instructions.
I then opened Qt Creator to the Welcome tag and selected "Open Project," then selected the program source directory 'biblioteq.win' and "configure project" which imported the project folder of the same name. Within the project folder is the file 'biblioteq.win.pro' a folder titled "biblioteq-source" and a folder titled "other files".
I clicked the 'biblioteq.win.pro' file and ran it using Kit = Destop Qt 6.7.1 MinGW 64-bit. This was fine at first, but towards the end it encounters an error. I have tried approaching this using both the latest (April 2024) release and second latest (March 2024) release of the program, each of which throws an error message at this point. I am not sure whether this error is an issue with my process or with the dev's code. I reached out to the dev, but they are using Linux and were unable to help.
The Output window gave the following as the error (see image also):
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lyaz5
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:313: release/BiblioteQ.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/QtBiblioteqSetup
biblioteq-2024.03.25/build/
Desktop_Qt_6_7_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:45: release] Error 2
22:45:45: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project biblioteq.win (kit: Desktop Qt 6.7.1 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Make"
Emphasized text is what appeared in red in the output window.
Advice on how to install correctly is appreciated.

@drescherjm Thanks! Is that a library that can be downloaded through the Qt manager, or do I have to locate it and install separately?

After I commented, I looked at the repository and I see that there are headers for yaz5 + a dll in the windows section but I didn't look at the exact contents on how the pro files link that library.
